# How to change the output color of a specific string, stored within an array, to Linux terminal?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm writing a small RPG in Python, and I want my different world objects to have varying colors.  I've tried exploring colorama and some similar modules; however, the string always prints as a small box with some numbers and letters in it, instead of, let's say, a blue '~' character for a water tile.

I create my world arrays with a variable that looks like this:

```
worldArray = [[' ' for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
```

I then add world objects to it through a few different functions, to structure a random-esque world environment, like this one:

```
def replacetiles(self, grid, row, a, b, char, count):
        while count:
            aShift = 2
            row_col_dict = {row: (a, b)}
            for row in row_col_dict.keys():
                startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

                for i in range(startPos, endPos):
                    grid[row][i] = char
                    
            row -= 1
            if aShift == 0:
                a += random.randint(1, 2)
            
            if count < 3:
                b -= (b / 2)
            
            b += random.randint(0, 1)
            aShift -=1
            count -= 1
```

This is of course all stored within a class object. This function is how I create randomized oceans within the world, by calling `replacetiles(gamemap, 9, 0, 5, '~', 3)`  which would replace a few of the indexes with `'~'`.

How would I be able to change the output color of the `'~'` within the game map?

EDIT: My question seems much more specific than the other thread listed.  The problem I am having, is when I print text through colorama, or any of the answers below or in the other thread, in a stand alone file simply printing colored text, it works.  However, when I use that same code to change the color of the `char` argument in `replacetiles`, I get this odd box icon, regardless of the method I used to change the color of the string text.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: What os/console are you using?

Comment: Newest version of Linux Mint available and the standard terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can add ASCII escape codes to the strings you add to your `worldArray`. To make your water blue, just replace `grid[row][i] = char` with `grid[row][i] = "\033[34m" + char + "\033[0m"`.

For more color codes, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

You can then print your world using:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in worldArray))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.  Still returns the strange box thing.

Comment: Can you paste what you see?

Comment: Added a screen shot to my main post.

Comment: Also, how are you actually printing your world?

Comment: `print '\n'.join(' '.join(*zip(*row)) for row in gamemap)` for the whole map.

Comment: That explains it. You're printing only the first char in each cell. Try this: `print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in gamemap))` (also see the answer)

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package called termcolor, instead of hard coding the values.

```
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red')
```

Comment: Also returns the weird box icon.  If I run this in its own file, I get the highlighted red text.  However, if I try to attach similar code into my function to change the `'~'` blue, I see the box icons. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: What terminal emulation are you using?

Comment: I have a fresh install of the newest version of Linux Mint, using the standard terminal. I added a screenshot to the main post for clarification.

Comment: It's an encoding problem, your are most likely trying to print a unicode character but your terminal doesn't support it. Try encoding the string or the single character with https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode.

Comment: No results from that.  My code is now: `grid[row][i] = char.encode('utf-8', 'strict')` Is this correct? The `char` argument being: `colored('w', 'blue', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])` I also changed the `'~'` symbol to a `'w'` instead to see if for some reason that would make a difference.

Comment: Once you have encode it, are you still trying to print it colorama? Perhaps the issue lies in the library. If utf-8 doesn't work try ascii.